# Cookies session and guid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am new to this cookies-session portion.

I need your help. Kindly give your suggestions.

In my application I'm using "UseCookies" in session state tag. So it takes the session value in cookies. So, if run my application in two tabs it shares the session value.

How to resolve this issue.

Its very important issue give your solution.

Comment: What do you want to be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your application in two different browser. Normally each browser keep cookies in different places, so each browser will create a new session cookie because cannot find what was created by another one.

Comment: but my user may open in same browser with 2 different tabs

Comment: May be you should store this value in another user-independent containers like ViewState, input type="hide", etc.?